# Does the factory specified in @PropertySources(@PropertySource(value="...",factory=), @PropertySource(factory)) be called for every file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What I'm trying to do is to override certain attributes from the base file based on the active profile. Something like this.

```
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-config")
    @PropertySources(
      {@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/configs/settings.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/configs/settings-${spring.profiles.active}.yml",
          factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)})
    public class SomeConfig {
     ....
    }
```

While debugging the code I noticed that none of the values were overridden. On further investigation I noticed that the factory was only called for the first file(which might be the issue). Does anyone has some idea on how to achieve overriding. I also noticed that the maps don't get overridden and I'll have to write some code to merge the two.

Comment: Don't assume that `spring.profiles.active` is a single profile, it is in fact an array. I would also suggest **not** to use the `@PropertySource` when using Spring BOot but rather specify `spring.config.additional-location` so that Spring Boot takes care of all this.